# Calling Ruby module methods from a nested class within

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an alternative to calling a Module method from a nested class? The code:

```
module GroupSweeper

  def expire_cache(paths)
    paths.each do |path|
      expire_page(path)
    end
  end

  class SweeperOne < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
    include GroupSweeper
    observe Subject
    def after_save(subject)
      expire_cache([root_path,subjects_path])
    end
    def after_destroy(subject)
      expire_cache([root_path,subjects_path])
    end 
  end

end
```

How can I call GroupSweeper's expire_cache method from within SweeperOne without explicitely including it?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some circular dependencies going on here.

- GroupSweeper defines a nested class
  of SweeperOne
- SweeperOne includes
  GroupSweeper

That won't work.

To answer your ruby method/nested class question:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method
    puts "yo yo yo"
  end

  class MySweetClass
    def sweet_method
      puts "swweeeeeeeeeeeet"
    end
  end
end
```

And you want to call MySweetClass's sweet_method, you would change to be:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method
    puts "yo yo yo"
    MySweetClass.new.sweet_method
  end

  class MySweetClass
    def sweet_method
      puts "swweeeeeeeeeeeet"
    end
  end
end

#....

class MyClass
  include MyModule
end

MyClass.new.my_method
```

However! I think you're on the wrong track regarding rails' sweepers. This answer is very tactical, but I think you should open a question about what you're trying to do regarding rails sweepers.

Comment: Thanks. I was originally trying to nest all my sweepers together in one file. However, I just learned that sweepers can observe multiple models--so I'm only going to need one.

Comment: But... what about if it is `MySweetClass` that have to call `my_method`??. As an example: A ruby service within a module that need to call shared methods from the module. These methods are shared with other ruby services from the same module

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong as i'm pretty new to ruby myself, but the class should probably not include the module that it itself is part of.

maybe if you close the module with an `end` including it from the class should work.